# Small Bottom Sheet Issue in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, debugging, bottom-sheet

I am using 3/4 size of bottomSheet in the page,
again open 1/4 size of bottomSheet in the same 3/4 size of bottomsheet page
(first Bottom sheet did not close)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the framework with its full potential. As official documentation states for method setFitToContents :

> Sets whether the height of the expanded sheet is determined by the
> height of its contents, or if it is expanded in two stages (half the
> height of the parent container, full height of parent container).
> Default value is true.

So all you need is set setFitToContent to false with:

```
behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(your_bottom_sheet_xml)
behavior.isFitToContents = false
behavior.halfExpandedRatio = 0.6f
```

With this 3-line-code the bottom sheet will expand till 60% of the screen at first, and afterwards it will fully expand to 100%.

Hope it can help someone!